# How to load resource bundle for inner class? using wicket 6.6

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.5

```
Unable to find property: 'registerform.agencyName.Required' for component:  [class=com.brazil.clasadm.application.AppnRegister$AppnRegisterForm].
```

My scenario is like:

```
public class AppnRegister extends someotherClass {

        public AppnRegister() {
            add(new AppnRegisterForm("registerform"));
        }
        class AppnRegisterForm extends Form {
        TextField agencyName= null;
        agencyName = new TextField("agencyName", new PropertyModel(cac, "agencyName"));
    agencyName .getLocalizer().getString("registerform.agencyName.Required", this);
        }
        }
```

I tried by adding the resource bundle by the names of AppnRegisterForm.properties, AppnRegister$AppnRegisterForm.properties and all in the same place of where the AppnRegister.java is present. But I unable to clear this issue. Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `AppnRegister` ? It must be a Wicket MarkupContainer but there is no `extends ...` in your code!

The inner class should be `static` to be able to reach it with `AppnRegister$AppnRegisterForm`.

Solutions:

- use `AppnRegister.properties`
- use `wicket-package.properties`

Both should be next to `AppnRegister.class` in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks martin, I will try and let you know

Comment: I kept wicket-package.properties inside the package where the .html and  .java files are present. it is working fine.